# Unity project not working when build with android studio

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Hi I have some problem when build my Unity project with android Studio.

First, my project is AR project using ARfoundation for Mobile(Android).

Buil and Run my project with Unity then ask camera permission and running well but when I export my project and build with android Studio, then it is not working(camera is not working) What would I do??

here is Log cast

E/Unity-ARCore: Failed to register lifecycle provider, Camera subsystem will be unavailable!

```
Failed to register lifecycle provider, Depth subsystem will be unavailable!

Failed to register lifecycle provider, Plane subsystem will be unavailable!

Failed to register lifecycle provider, Raycast subsystem will be unavailable!

Failed to register lifecycle provider, ReferencePoint subsystem will be unavailable!

Failed to register lifecycle provider, Session subsystem will be unavailable!

Failed to register lifecycle provider, Input subsystem will be unavailable!
```

Comment: Why do you wanna build it with Android Studio if you already built and run it with Unity. I don't get it. Are you trying to add non-AR features to your Unity project with Android Studio?

Comment: First, I wanna read android profiling(cpu,memory ect of my android) and just Android Camera is not working I sure that because UI object is runing

Comment: Well you gotta be more specific how are you running an ARFoundation app with Android Studio. ARFoundation is for Unity not for Android Studio, it wont work on Android Studio. Also you can profile your games on Android built with Unity as [well](https://docs.unity3d.com/540/Documentation/Manual/Profiler.html).

Comment: Hmm, First in Unity File->Build Setting, and Switch platform to Android and Checking Export project, then Unity Create my project Folder for Android Studio and runnig that Folder(include my Unity project) with Abdroid Studio

Comment: Okay as i said that is only for using your Unity app on Android Studio. You can add more Android Studio features to your App BUT Android Studio wont be running your C# scripts. It just embeds it to your Android Studio code. Therefore, you can not profile them. To do so you gotta use Unity Profiler.

Comment: Hmm.. Actually I can profiled other Unity project with Android Studio... I think it is Camera permission issue

Comment: Well even so that is not necessary you can do it on Unity. There is no need to built your project and importing to Android Studio

Answer (score 0):

Hi I solved My problem

Here is Ref URL: https://gogorchg.tistory.com/entry/Android-Android-Studio-20-Instant-Run-%EB%81%84%EA%B8%B0

Thank you